# Firebase: How to convert an anonymous account to a permanent google account

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've been trying to convert an anonymous account to a permanent google account following the instructions on the firebase docs (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth#google-sign-in)

It shows the following snippet of code:

```js
import { GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";

const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token);
```

However, the snippet of code provided displays a variable called "googleUser" which has the method `googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token`

I do not know where this variable comes from and how to get it. I've looked around the docs and internet for hours and had no luck.

I'm currently using `linkWithPopup` to do the job, however, if the google user that I'm trying to link the anonymous account to already exists on the app it just fails.

Comment: on this page (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider) It says that  "\`googleUser\` from the onsuccess Google Sign In callback." But I still don't know how to get it,.

Answer (score 1):

you should use the method linkWithPopup for that. here is an example:

```js
import {
  getAuth,
  linkWithPopup,
  GoogleAuthProvider,
} from 'firebase/auth'

export function linkWithGoogleAccount() {
  var anonymousUser = getAuth().currentUser
  // Authenticate with a second method and get a credential
  var provider = new GoogleAuthProvider()
  if (anonUser)
    return linkWithPopup(anonymousUser, provider)
  else return null
}
```

Comment: You can also use linkWithRedirect like linkWithRedirect(auth.currentUser, provider), [docs here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking?hl=en)